# File not found: Package pgf Warning: Your graphic driver pgfsys-dvips.def does not support fadings. This warning is given only once on input line 31

Tags: errors

i use Texmaker 5.0.3 and Miktex 2.9

When i compile simple file main.tex with Latex or pdfLaTex, always error:

File not found

Log:

Package pgf Warning: Your graphic driver pgfsys-dvips.def does not support fadings. This warning is given only once on input line 31.

Minimal coding:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
My box.
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Please help,
Thanks

Comment: your minimal example doesn't load fadings. But beside this: use pdflatex or lualatex or xelatex if you want to use fadings, with latex + dvips it won't work.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer thanks. But how can set to load fadings?

Comment: As you did in the images, but not in the code.